# Is there a way to control the range selectors range?

Tags: dygraphs

I am using the range selector on my graph that shows number values over time. (using dygraphs).  Is there a way I can control the range that is selected pragmatically?  Like when the graph loads have the entire dataset load, but only have the last 1 days worth of data in the range selector?  I would like to have my entire dataset shown, but be able to set the max/min of the range selector to specific values. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the [`dateWindow` option](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#dateWindow) (you use this option even when your x-axis is numeric, rather than date-like).

For example, when you're creating the chart:

`new Dygraph(div, data, { dateWindow: [first, last] })`

or after the chart has been created:

`g.updateOptions({dateWindow: [first, last]});`

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I need!